# Drupal 7 add calendar module. Doubleclick on a day to add calender item for that day

Tags: 7, views, datetime

Adding 50+ calender items to my drupal Calendar is a pain and takes a lot of time clicking and selecting the right date.
What would be awesome is that it would be possible to just doubleclick or click on a + or something on the day that needs a new calender item.
Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?
Or something similar.
I already added the link to add a calendar item above the calendar to add a calendar item from that view but then I still need to change the date unless it is the current day.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for calendar module, not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Calendar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) does not provide such a feature per se. There is also another calendar module, [FullCalendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fullcalendar). This uses the [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://fullcalendar.io/). By default the Drupal module does not provide this functionality, but from the [demo pages](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/selectable.html) it seems that it is a relatively easy one to implement by yourself. You would have to study the demo a bit.

Comment: Thank you, saw some stuff about that module before but now I know it is pretty much the way to go. That full calendar is pretty awesome.

Comment: @user1541645 welcome, I have used the module extensively in one of my projects and I am quite pleased myself. Be careful though, it becomes slow for views that return a large number of events (1000+).

Comment: It would suprise me that on any of my websites we would hit 100+ events, thanks for the advice!